# python divisorGenerator -changes behavior with bigger numbers

Tags: python

I tried to create a generator, that returns the proper divisors of n (not including n itself). It works fine until 256, but starts including n starting from 257 ... I could not figure out why. Thanks for your help!

```
def divisorGenerator(n):
    large_divisors = []
    y = int(math.sqrt(n))
    for i in xrange(1, y + 1):
        if n % i is 0:
            yield i
            if i is not n / i and n is not n / i:   
                large_divisors.insert(0, n / i)
    for divisor in large_divisors:
        yield divisor
```

Comment: ok, thanks! obviously changing 'is not' to '!=' made the difference. Anybody, who can explain to me why 256 or 257 made a difference before?

Comment: from the link by @ŁukaszR: "In your case, the second test only works because Python caches small integer objects, which is an implementation detail. For larger integers, this does not work", see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/pythons-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers which links to http://docs.python.org/c-api/int.html